# Internet Message ID FROM EWS Managed API Send Email c#

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I am trying to discover if there is a way to determine the internet message ID after sending an email using the EWS Managed API. I understand you can go in there and get the results from the sent box, but the server that is sending these emails is sending multiple emails at a time from different services.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't, basically because EWS sends message Asynchronously the Id isn't available see https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/dd034b8c-ffa1-4ae0-9025-45fcf520c9e5/updateitem-does-not-return-itemid?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment

As a work around you might want to consider setting the Internet messageId on the Message before you send it. As long as it valid and unique it should work okay eg

```
        ExtendedPropertyDefinition PidTagInternetMessageId = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(4149, MapiPropertyType.String);
        EmailMessage ema = new EmailMessage(service);
        ema.Subject ="test from ews";
        ema.Body = new MessageBody("test<br>Rgds<>");
        ema.ToRecipients.Add("gscales@domain.com");
        ema.SetExtendedProperty(PidTagInternetMessageId,("<" +Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "@domain.com>"));
        ema.SendAndSaveCopy();
```

Also if you save the message first as a draft before sending it the server will assign the MessageId property which which should then be able to read back using Load.

Cheers
Glen

Comment: Perfect... Thanks a lot!!