# EWS Managed API: External GUID in mail message?

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

Is it possible to assign EmailMessage specific GUID/ID, which will be later used for search?

```
var email = new EmailMessage(_service);
email.ExternalGuid = /*Guid or Identifier*/;
email.Send();
```

And later I should be able to use it to find if this mail is present:

```
var isExist = _service.IsExistByExternalGuid(/*Guid or Identifier*/);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the InternetMessageid eg [Internet Message ID FROM EWS Managed API Send Email c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35073995/internet-message-id-from-ews-managed-api-send-email-c-sharp?rq=1) this Id will then appear in any tracking logs associated with the Message and you can search for the message at a later date using a SearchFilter eg

```
     ItemView ivew = new ItemView(3);
  service.TraceEnabled = true;
  ExtendedPropertyDefinition PidTagInternetMessageId = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(4149, MapiPropertyType.String);
  SearchFilter sf = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(PidTagInternetMessageId, MessageID);
  FindItemsResults<Item> iCol = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, sf, ivew);

  foreach (Item item in iCol.Items)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(item.Subject);
  }
```